# the 'if...else' is not checking any other conditions, directly skipping to last 'else' statement

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

i,m calling a JavaScript function to change an image by using if..else statement to change its source. but it directly skips to last else statement, so the image only keeps swapping between first & last image

JavaScript function:

```
function myfunction2() {
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
    //iterartion 1
    if (image.src == "img1.jpg") {
        image.src = "img2.jpg";
    } else if (image.src == "img2.jpg") {
        image.src = "img3.jpg";
    } else if (image.src == "img3.jpg") {
        image.src = "img4.jpg";
    } else if (image.src == "img4.jpg") {
        image.src = "img5.jpg";
    } else if (image.src == "img5.jpg") {
        image.src = "img1.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "img2.jpg";
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<div id="image-slider">
            <img src="img1.jpg" id="image">

            <div id="left-holder">
            <img onclick="myfunction2()" src="arrow-left.png" height="49px" width="49px" class="left"/>
            </div>

            <div id="right-holder">
            <img  onclick="myfunction2()" src="arrow-right.png" height="49px" width="49px" class="right"/>
            </div>
</div>
```

what am i doin wrong here? plz help.

Comment: for image, you are giving this as absolute path? This is not the absolute path, you are giving as relative path. And in your condition path would be absolute.So it will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript code image.src gives something like *"file:///C:/Users/guser/Desktop/img1.jpg"*
So instead of if(image.src == "img1.jpg") use if(image.src.indexOf("img1.jpg") != -1)

That means "img1.jpg" is present in absolute path of image.src

Answer (score 2):

Try using [trim()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) function

```
    function myfunction2() {
        var image = document.getElementById("image");
image = image.trim();
        //iterartion 1
        if (image.src == "img1.jpg") {
            image.src = "img2.jpg";
        } else if (image.src == "img2.jpg") {
            image.src = "img3.jpg";
        } else if (image.src == "img3.jpg") {
            image.src = "img4.jpg";
        } else if (image.src == "img4.jpg") {
            image.src = "img5.jpg";
        } else if (image.src == "img5.jpg") {
            image.src = "img1.jpg";
        } else {
            image.src = "img2.jpg";
        }
    }
```

I doubt that there might be spaces surrounding your text